# Taxes won't update in DoExpressCheckoutPayment with Paypal Express Checkout

Tags: paypal

We use Express Checkout and want to calculate taxes based on the shipping address chosen on PayPal during checkout. We can increase the order total to account for taxes, but the tax amount is always recorded as zero. Here is our flow:

We `SetExpressCheckout` with `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT` as order total, `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT` as zero (or left out), and a `MAXAMT` of order total + maximum possible tax.

On callback we run `GetExpressCheckoutDetails` to find the shipping address.

If there are taxes we run `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` with `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT` as (order total + taxes), and `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT` and `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT0` as taxes.

The total order is processed with amount (order total + taxes) but the `PAYMENTINFO_0_TAXAMT` returned is still always zero.

Is there an additional field that needs to be passed to apply taxes correctly?

Setup:

```
METHOD: "SetExpressCheckout"  
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION: "SALE"  
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT: 1.00  
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT: 1.00  
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT: 0  
MAXAMT: 1.1  
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0: 1  
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0: 1.0
```

Capture:

```
METHOD: "DoExpressCheckoutPayment" 
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION: "SALE"
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT: 1.1
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT: 1.1
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT: 0.1
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT: 0
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT0: 0.1
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0: 1.0
```

Result:

```
ACK: "Success"
VERSION: "95"
BUILD: "7161310"
PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONTYPE: "cart"
PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTTYPE: "instant"
PAYMENTINFO_0_AMT: "1.10"
PAYMENTINFO_0_FEEAMT: "0.33"
PAYMENTINFO_0_TAXAMT: "0.00"
PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS: "Completed"
```

Comment: Can you provide the full API requests that you are sending over so that I can see what all is being passed over and what may be causing your issue.  Please leave out your API credentials.

Comment: Sure - just added the two requests and the response, with some of the fields omitted (like auth and seller/payer account info)

Comment: @PP_MTS_Chad I think it works if I run a second SetExpressCheckout, along with the token and the updated tax value, before running DoExpressCheckout. Is that right?